# Masonry not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to integrate Masonry Jquery into my Squarespace site on the blog list, and believe to have set it up correctly, however it's not working.

The site I am working on is: http://levelupreviews.squarespace.com/blog

I have uploaded the script files in the scripts folder and inserted the javascript after the end body tag.  See here:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){

    var $container = $('#container');

    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.blog-list-container'
      });
    });

  });
</script>
```

I'm not too familiar with Jquery so any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 itemSelector : '.blog-list-container'
```

this should be applied to the item , not the container.

so change this to :

```
itemSelector : '.blog-cards'
```

just in case you are using different plugin , this is the one im talking about :

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Ah that makes sense, Ok.  Just changed it, however it doesn't seem to be working.. any thoughts?

Comment: umm maybe you should try removinf $ from container so your code will be :$(function(){

    var container = $('#container');

    container.imagesLoaded( function(){
      container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.blog-cards'
      });
    });

  }); , and insert this snippet in $("document").ready(function(){})

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Jquery wasn't working for some reason but it did once I changed it to:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){

        var $container = $('.content');
    // initialize
    $container.masonry({
      columnWidth: 20,
      itemSelector: '.blog-cards'
    });

  });
</script>
```

Woohoo!